# Using SpringBoot CrudRepository to find one known entry

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, repository

I am currently working with a project that uses SpringBoot.

I have created a tabled called configuration_documents using Hibernate.  This table can store different types of document objects that I have created.

One of the document objects I have created is Index, and I want to retrieve Index data, so I created a repository like this:

```
public interface IndexRepository extends CrudRepository<Index, Long> {
}
```

I know for a fact that the configuration_document table should only have one entry of Index, or else just return the 1st Index in the table.  What is best way of implementing this?

Without modifying IndexRepository, I am currently thinking of something like this (The IndexRepository is autowired in):

```
StreamSupport.stream(this.configurationRepository.findAll().spliterator(), false).
                map(
                    return Index;
                ).//A Collector here perhaps?
```

Thanks.

Comment: So if I get it right, you can have different configuration document types in the same table, right?

Comment: @NiVeR Yes and for each document I have a different Repository.  Thanks.

Comment: Using findAll() means you will fetch all of the documents of that type into memory and then operate on them.  It is usually better to select the document that you want to fetch in the query.  For example if your table has 50,000 documents of which 10,000 are of type Index and you're interested in 1 of them, it's better to fetch just that one rather than 10,000 or 50,000.  To do this with Spring you'd use a findBy... method.  If you provide the table and entity definitions I can show you how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

So,to my knowledge, you can't query based on row number using `jpa`. In `jpa` you must specify a `By` parameter to serve as where clause. Refer to the [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods) for the Query Methods you can compose.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Top` and `First` keywords while constructing your queries, here [is the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.7.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result).

You have to declare method like this:

```
Index findFirstIndex();
```

in the `IndexRepository` and that will solve your problem.

Alternatively if you're not allowed to modify `IndexRepository` you can fetch the first result using streams API somehow like this

```
indexRepository.findAll().stream()
        .findFirst()
        .orElseThrow(
                () -> new IndexNotFoundException("Index cannot be found")
        );
```

But the first option would be much more optimal.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I suggest you to think what do you want to do with that `Index` in the future. 
In case it is just readonly immutable entity then probably the best option is to make some 'IndexHolder' component inject entity into it just after application start (using raw EntityManager for example) and use this component to access `Index` across the application.

But I'm assuming that you want to be able to update `Index` as well.
So in this case I can suggest extending an `org.springframework.data.repository.Repository` instead of `CrudRepository`. It will limit the possible set of operation on `Index` entity to NONE but we're still be able to use spring-data features.

So the repository might look like this:

```
// Can only insert/update index entity for now
interface IndexRepository extends Repository<Index, String> {

    Index save(Index index);
}
```

Obviously it isn't enough, we need at least a retrieve operation.
And here I suggest to rely on some `fixed` ID for `Index`.
It could be some value out of sequence range or '0' or guid (depends on what you're using).

Then we will need to enforce using this ID on all persistence operations with this entity, but as a result query will be fast and simple.

I suppose you're modeling your classes like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "configuration_documents")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type")
@DiscriminatorValue("DOCUMENT")
public class ConfigurationDocument {
    @Id
    private String id;

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

@Entity(name = "Index")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type")
@DiscriminatorValue("INDEX")
public class Index extends ConfigurationDocument {
    ...
}
```

Let's add that fixed id:

```
@Entity(name = "Index")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type")
@DiscriminatorValue("INDEX")
@EntityListeners(Index.IndexPersistentId.class)
public class Index extends ConfigurationDocument {
    //This is going to be our fixed id.
    public static final String INDEX_ID = "42";

    public static class IndexPersistentId {
        @PrePersist
        public void prePersist(Index index) {
            index.setId(INDEX_ID); //enforce using fixed ID
        }
    }
}
```

And the last step is to add a retrieve operation to the repository:

```
interface IndexRepository extends Repository<Index, String> {
    @Query("select i from Index i where i.id = :#{T(com.stackoverflow.so44249828.Index).INDEX_ID}")
    Index load();

    Index save(Index index);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In spring jpa, you could limit the result as shown following:

```
public interface IndexRepository extends CrudRepository<Index, Long> {

           Index findFirstByOrderByIdAsc();
    }
```

reference

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result

Answer (score 0):

I remember seen something similar to what you are searching for.  But can't find that source anymore.

You can still keep the same repository as what you have right now:

```
public interface IndexRepository extends CrudRepository<Index, Long> {
}
```

As for the streaming part, you can do a filter instance of the Index class and get the first instance of that at the same time in the same line of code, like this:

```
Optional<Index> optional = StreamSupport.stream(repository.findAll().sliterator(), false)
                                        .filter(i -> i instanceof Index)
                                        .findFirst();
```

This should be most direct to what you are asking for.